# sequential execution of a group of commands (subroutine like)

Tags: manipulate

I have a set of data all formed via AppendTo and like to apply them synchronously and consecutively to a group of commands, much like a  in a subroutine. The commands in that "subroutine" are not aware of the structure of the input data/parameters nor that these commands are being asked to execute consecutively.

Comment: I don’t understand what the question is. Please edit the question to include more detail. If possible, include example input and what kind of output you would like, any code that you’ve tried so far, and a more complete description of what your issue is or what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am reading from a multiple of sources each recording a time slice of a separate aspect of an event in progress, say, input streams from separate detector elements of an array of detectors. Now I also have a routine that take one time slice from all of the input streams and computes something based on these pieces of information and send the results to different plotting routines to display the real time scenario at the output device, for example, a radar screen. Does that make more sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) for a sequence of operations

```
Composition[f, g, h][x]

(* f[g[h[x]]] *)
```

Or in shorthand

```
f@*g@*h@x

(* f[g[h[x]]] *)

% === %%

(* True *)
```

For a list of data

```
data = Array[x, 5]

(* {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]} *)

Composition[f, g, h] /@ data

(* {f[g[h[x[1]]]], f[g[h[x[2]]]], f[g[h[x[3]]]], f[g[h[x[4]]]], f[g[h[x[5]]]]} *)

f@*g@*h /@ data

(* {f[g[h[x[1]]]], f[g[h[x[2]]]], f[g[h[x[3]]]], f[g[h[x[4]]]], f[g[h[x[5]]]]} *)

% === %%

(* True *)
```